# How can I enlarge a twitter button?

Tags: css, twitter

I have the code from the developers site:

```
<div id="custom-tweet-button"><a target="_blank" class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Hey! 20% off!" data-count="none">Tweet to Friends</a></div>
```

but it's just ignoring the css I already tried to even place it inline but I can't. I googled for it but the best I found was on eHow.com and they just suggested to use another type of button. (I'm using the one without count)

Comment: Have you included the CSS stylesheet?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about this not too long ago, but with Google Plus. What I did was to look at the css that plus used, then created my own stylesheet (using the same rules) but with the `!important` tag to replace the original ones. This was successful with Google Plus (got a nice button that was 120x120px), so i'd imagine the same could be used for twitter.

When I was working out what needed to be done, I used chrome's inspect element to find what stylesheets were being used.

Comment: this is actually a great idea thanks, however I think twitter uses an image (I just noticed - not 100% sure yet, still looking through the code) can that be replaced?

Comment: well, the images are usually set in css using either `background` or `background-image`. you can clear those, on replace them in your own css. If that doesn't work, you could use jquery to find and edit the images within the twitter area and replace them. granted, that will cause flickering, but it should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own Twitter Tweet button with CSS [as explained here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button#build-your-own).

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
      #custom-tweet-button a {
        display: block;
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 20px;
        background: url('http://a4.twimg.com/images/favicon.ico') 1px center no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
      }
</style>

<div id="custom-tweet-button">  
      <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
</div>
```

When using this method you have to use query string parameters to customize the Tweet Button's behavior as well as handle the popup of the Share Box.

Comment: I tried to do exactly that, it just isn't taking the css actually in the code I placed here it's wrapped around the #custom-tweet-button div =/

Comment: You have to make sure you're not using the iFrame version of the Twitter button code, but the custom version that uses just an anchor.  Example:  http://www.joeleckroth.com/so/8246042.html  -  The customized button just uses an anchor with params added to the anchor url.